# How to count same record row in db and show number in label

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table name tblb which has one column journal name, where I store journal name.

How do I write the sql query to count journal name with same name and show the number in a label?
For example 
In tblb

```
 Journalname 
-----
abc
abc
abc
def
def
```

On input through textbox and on button click eg

```
textbox.Text = "abc";
label.Text = 3;

textbox.Text = "def";
label.Text = 2;
```

Comment: Like wise howmany textBoxes you have arranged in the UI? What happens if a new  `Journalname` is added

Answer (score 0):

Get the return from your select after grouping

```
    select journalname, count(0) [count] from tblb group by journalname;
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL :**

```
SELECT Journalname, COUNT(*) [Count] FROM tblb
GROUP BY Journalname
```

**Datatable:**

```
var results = (from j in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              group j by j["Journalname"].ToString() into grp
              select new 
              {
                 Journalname = grp.key.ToString(),
                 Count = grp.Count()
              }).ToList();
```

You can now loop through the results and update UI:

```
foreach(var journal in results)
{
    // Update UI - Choose appropriate text box for each journal
    textbox.Text = journal.Journalname;
    label.Text = journal.Count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server a statement like this:

```
SELECT     Journalname, COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM         tblb
GROUP BY Journalname
//Add this line if you want to display only duplicate values
//HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Will return something like this:

```
Journalname | dupes  
abc         | 3 
def         | 2
```

On your code you will have to loop through the SQL results and to display it on your page.